# Delay Request in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, httprequest

How can I delay HTTP requests addressing a ASP.NET application?

The delay have to be before processing the request at the server.

Additionally I like to select which request ought to have the delay.

**Why do I want the delay?**

Some requests throw an exception in the KernelBase.dll. 
Delaying the requests grants the application some time to initialize the data so that the exception is not thrown any more.

Comment: Perhaps look to initialising the data in the application start?

Comment: I'd be tempted to initialise the data on first, forcing any request to wait for available data

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand about your requirement, i will be tempted to add some sort of spin wait in Application BeginRequest event handler.
You can choose whether to invoke the timer, based on conditions in the request or state of the application(includes data initialization state) at that moment.